# If $X_n \longmapsto X$ in law and $Y_n \longmapsto Y$ in law then $X_n +Y_n \longmapsto X+Y$ in law?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

We say that given a sequence of random variable $(X_n)_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ defined on $(\Omega_n,\mathcal{A}_n,P_n)$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$ *converge in law* to $X$ random variable if $PX_n \to P_x$ in the sense $\forall \hspace{0.1cm} f \in C_b(\mathbb{R}^d) \hspace{0.1cm} \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \underset{n}{\longmapsto} \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$

Is holds that if $X_n \overset{\mathscr{L}}{\longmapsto} X, \hspace{0.1cm} Y_n \overset{\mathscr{L}}{\longmapsto} Y$ then $X_n+Y_n \overset{\mathscr{L}}{\longmapsto} X+Y$ ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1111276/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative.

Take, for example, $X_n=Z$ and $Y_n=-Z$, where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Then $X_n\xrightarrow{L}N(0,1)$ and $Y_n\xrightarrow{L}N(0,1)$, but $X_n+Y_n=0$ for each $n\ge1$.